# Read <input> value inside view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Hi i want to create table that has as many rows as user can set in input field.

how to do that instead of 5 in for loop i have value specified in input tag ?

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewProces", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))

    @<input type="number" value="5" min="1" name="rowsNumber" />

    @<table>
        @For i As Integer = 0 To 5
            @<tr>
                <td>Row @i</td>
            </tr>
      Next i
    </table>

End Using
```

EDIT:
Ok i decided to change some things but now it still doesent work ;/ this is what i try now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.rowsNumber').on('input', function () {
        alert("Value Changed");
    });
</script>
```

and here is my htlm.textboxfor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.NumberOfRows, New With {.class = "rowsNumber"})
```

Comment: do you use a viewmodel for this view? If not, you really should, because then you can switch the `"manually written input"` for [TextBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: ok so i'll create viewmodel with rowsnumber integer and then how to dynamicly change the table to specifed value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do this client-side, not server-side.  The server-side code can't read the value of the `input` *before the page has even been rendered*.

So your view markup would simplify:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewProces", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))

    @<input type="number" value="5" min="1" name="rowsNumber" />

    @<table id="myTable">
    </table>

End Using
```

Then you'd attach a JavaScript handler to the `input` to modify the table.  It might have a structure that's something like this:

```
$('input[name="rowsNumber"]').on('input', function () {

    var existingRowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
    var newRowCount = parseInt($(this).val());

    if (newRowCount == existingRowCount) {
        return;
    }

    if (newRowCount > existingRowCount) {
        // append new rows to the table
    }

    if (newRowCount < existingRowCount) {
        // remove trailing rows from the table
    }
});
```

Comment: @JakubWisniewski: What is the resulting client-side code?  When you debug this in your browser, is the event handler attached at all?  Is it an old browser and doesn't support the `input` event?

Comment: Yeah. I had some minor errors in developer tolls of webbrowser :)